# How can I remove the last part of a file after a specific text which has different positions?

Tags: python, if-statement

I have many different text files with different structures. But all of them have a at some point the same text ('TS    1234000'). I want to delete in all these files the text after TS 178000 including the line with TS.

I have written something but it does not work:

```
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as input1_dat_file, \
     open('output.txt', 'w') as out:
         f = input1_dat_file.readline()
         if f.startswith('TS   1234000'):
             print("I have found it")
             sys.exit() 
         else: 
             out.writelines()
```

the outpot file has no text in it.

the input data is like this:

```
TS 8888
1
2
3
4
5 6
88
TS    1234000
2
3
8
9
56
```

Comment: hint: you read a line from input1_data_file, look at it and then throw it away

Comment: I see. You got write. I have to strip lines isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be looking for `sed '/^TS    1234000/q'` but here's a quick way to reimplement it in Python.

```
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as inputfile, open('output.txt', 'w') as out:
     for line in inputfile:
         if line.startswith('TS    1234000'):
             break
             #print("I have found it")
             #sys.exit() 
         out.write(line)
```

Reading just a line at a time avoids pulling the entire file into memory, so should scale to arbitrarily large files, and the logic seems slightly more straightforward than your attempt.

There is no need to `strip` the newline because `write` doesn't add one.

Comment: but this script extracts just the last line.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. It breaks out of the loop if it finds a match. If it's still inside the loop, it writes the line it just read, and starts over at the beginning of the loop.  I had a typo which is fixed now (your sample contains four spaces after TS while your code attempt had three) and I carelessly forgot to replace `f` with `line` in the `startswith`.